# Unable to implement a retry for a webhook activity in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-automation

I have an Azure Data Factory V2 Pipeline with a Webhook Activity, and it has been working correctly, however I've been experiencing some 'Bad Request' errors, due the network and/or availability issues with the Azure Automation Service.

The solution here is to manually re-run this pipeline and works, is there a way of adding a retry like the CopyActivity to a Webhook Activity in ADF V2? and if that is not possible, are there any workarounds that you might know?

[image]

Not sure if this is possible now but I created a feature suggestion:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38096407-add-retry-policy-to-webhook-activity

Comment: Alternative is to use WebActivity, which has retry option.. you can have ForEach  Activity with Wait activity combination with 30 sec or 1 min wait interval in case you want to re-try based on few scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use WebActivity, which has retry option.. you can have ForEach Activity with Wait activity combination with 30 sec or 1 min wait interval in case you want to re-try based on few scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to dodge Webhook activity and use Web Activity. Just make sure that you add response to your HTTP Listener like Logic App. Here is a blog which elucidates on the same:
https://www.data4v.com/making-adf-web-activity-synchronous-with-logic-app/